# How can I upgrade a socket to TLS in node?

Tags: node.js, ftp, openssl, ssl

I'm trying to write an FTP server in Node which supports TLS with explicit AUTH. In this mode, the client sends an `AUTH TLS` command to the server, which responds with an acknowledgement, prompting the client to begin negotiating a secure connection.

I'm using this code to upgrade the connection: https://github.com/andris9/rai/blob/master/lib/starttls.js . I've verified that this works by writing a simple echo server using net.Server, and then using the `starttls` function to immediately upgrade the socket to a secure connection. Connecting to this test server using `openssl s_client` works as expected.

However, when I try to connect to my test FTP server using an FTP client supporting TLS with explicit auth, the following exception is raised by the object returned by `createSecurePair`:

```
[Error: 140735236446560:error:1408A0B7:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no ciphers     
 specified:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_srvr.c:1009:
]
```

I have in fact specified ciphers (`createSecurePair` is passed an `options` dict with `ciphers` set to 'RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA'). I've packet-sniffed the connection, and what seems to happen is that after the server responds to the client's `AUTH TLS` command, there is a brief interchange between client and server which I assume is the (failed) TLS negotiation. But I don't really understand enough about TLS to investigate any further. How should I go about investigating the source of this error?

I am running node 0.8.1, and had the same issue with 0.6.19.

Comment: The error clearly indicates that no cipher is being sent in the Client Hello. You can try to decode the packet as SSL using ethreal and try to see if ciphers are present in the Client Hello packet being sent by you.

Comment: That's weird, since my program is the server, not the client, and I've tried with a couple of FTP clients. Seems unlikely that they'd both be buggy in that respect. (Unless the TLS client/server terminology is different from what I'm expecting?)Thanks for the ethereal suggestion.

Comment: It seems that the FTP client is sending a correct Client Hello message, but the server never responds with a Server Hello. So there must be a bug in my code somewhere. It's just hard to figure out where because the code for upgrading the connection is known to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out just to be a silly mistake. The FTP server code I was modifying used `socket.setEncoding`. Of course, having this turned on screwed up the TLS negotiation.